# Vim: How to trace what plugin is responsible for a feature?

Tags: vim

I just installed the dotfiles from this repo: https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

When I try to save one of my javascript file a lint section appears. However I don't know which plugin it's coming from:

[image]

Is there a way to find out where this is coming from? I tried deleting a plugin that I thought was responsible but it's just trial and error. Is there a more systematic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

That feature is provided by a plugin called [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic), itself a third-party wrapper around built-in features (`:help :make`, `:help quickfix`), themselves using external programs (most likely [`eslint`](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/settings/syntastic.vim#L12)). You <strike>should</strike> *must* read the documentation of that plugin: `:help syntastic`.

### Long answer

The *whole* point of customization is to adjust *your* environment to *your* needs. This is done by:

1. identifying your needs/problems,
2. looking for solutions that don't create more needs/problems,
3. putting them in practice.

By downloading *someone else*'s config you essentially **gave up** before the first step. *Your* environment is now adjusted to *someone else*'s needs and is full of settings and plugins you may or may not need, that may or may not suit your needs. *You* willingly chose to install a black box *you* don't understand instead of actually learning *your* editor and configuring *your* environment to suit *your* needs.

You wanted a quick install and you get an impenetrable mess. I'd suggest you get rid of all that crap ASAP.

Lack of curiosity will get you nowhere, especially in programming.

Comment: yea totally agree. i want to start from scratch. is there a quick way to uninstall the dotfiles?